# Can a creature with multiple attacks per Attack action make all of their attacks if they are incapacitated after making the first attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, multiattack

The *Player's Handbook* states (emphasis mine):

> An incapacitated creature can’t take **actions** or **reactions**.

Suppose I am fighting a creature that has a multiattack, and I have an ability that can incapacitate a creature as a reaction. If the creature has completed the first attack in its multiattack, could I prevent the remainder of its attacks with my ability? Or is it too late, since the remaining attacks aren't actions?

Comment: A Readied action to cast Tasha's Hideous Laughter is one example of this.

Comment: That issue being marked as duplicate discusses the stunned condition. The answers refer to things such as being unable to move or speak. Simply being incapacitated without being stunned may have different repercussions.

Comment: I've reopened this question as the linked question concerned being stunned (which includes incapacitation), but has other features that make the answers there unhelpful for this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Taking an action" is not a point in time thing (necessarily), it is a duration. The Dash action is being taken throughout your movement, the Readied action is being taken from the point of declaration through to the trigger (or your next turn), the Dodge action is being taken from this turn to your next turn.

Therefore, if you become "unable to take actions" your ongoing action just stops, from this point forward, you can't take it anymore.

Comment: Got some backup for that? Something in the books that shows what you're describing?

Comment: @Chemus you mean other than that the normal way of following any procedure is to execute the steps in the order they are given?

Comment: Even if that's not explicitly stated anywhere in the rules, I'd say it's a valid interpretation of the phrase "take [an] action," which is how I've always seen the phrase written in the rules. Works for me.